# C reading input in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, int, eof, getchar

In c what does this do after gets

```
int c; 
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

I saw that many of you are telling me its while loop and all, why so much complication to it? Why cant we just use this code which I have given below?

```
gets(name);
if(name == '\n'|| name == EOF) 
    gets(name);`
```

Comment: You mean that when address of string `name` is new line or EOF, we should read the string again?

Comment: Do understand what `==` means in `C`?

Comment: The original program simply waits until the end of file is reached or until a newline occurs and then continues with execution.

Comment: `name` is an array of characters or a pointer to an array of characters.  `name == '\n'` is trying to compare an array (or pointer) to a constant number like the code for a line-feed or `10`.  How does comparing an array to 10 make sense?

Comment: @fanton yes I know ..== this compares, = this one assigns..

Comment: @chux just learning ! not writing operating system yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this piece of code

```
int c; 
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n');
```

is used to clear the buffer, as mentioned in @napnac's answer. It is mainly used instead of `fflush (stdin);`, which is UB. But note that this is successful only if the input buffer happens to contain data ending in a newline.

Otherwise, you can use `fflush (stdin);`, which is not recommended. You can also use the [`flushinp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/flushinp) function provided by the curses library. It throws away any typeahead that has been typed by the user and has not yet been read by the program

Comment: thanks now i get it.

Comment: ok ..but that would cost you 5 rupees. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of, the `gets` function is not really secure and you might want to use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead.

Anyway, your piece of code is used to *clear the buffer*. When you read from the user input, all the things that the user will type is going to be stored in a [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_buffer), and then the program will read from it. That why sometimes you need to clear the buffer so you don't read other things that you didn't want.